# Is "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" an acceptable edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

I would like to know if Neo's [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/157312/8) to my post is an acceptable change to my contribution?

He changed about 3500 characters to:

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx

I see that he is a mod here and I don't really think this was very professional of him

The post cites a genuine, on-going problem. I don't know exactly how to deal with it so I came to this site for help.

It seems too hard a question for this site, so I know to take my query elsewhere, but is @Neo's edit an acceptable change to my post?

Comment: it WAS x-rated, so it seems ok to me.

Comment: -1 means no on Meta, right?

Comment: @guest It usually means that the voter disagrees with what stated or questioned in the post. Which is, in this case, arguing that removing x-rated content from a post was unprofessional or wrong (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the actual [revision history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/157312/revisions) you'll see that you engaged in an edit war with another moderator who tried to remove the inappropriate elements of your post. You insisted on rolling those edits back and combined with the negative reception this resulted in your post being deleted. Neo later replaced that wall of text which could still be considered offensive and trolling in nature. I would have done the same to avoid further flags as high-rep users can still see deleted posts.

All that being said I do wonder why you feel the need to point out the edit when you should probably focus more on the extremely negative score your post received and its subsequent deletion.

Comment: I could not have stated this better myself.

Comment: Just noticed the revision history, not only was it X-rated, but there was lots of rolling around going on as well